# Changing the file to which your command history is recorded?

Tags: bash, command-history

Is there an environment variable you can use in Linux to send your command history to a different file?

The reason I ask is that I'm interested in recording my shell sessions into different files for referencing later.

I know I could use auditd or something like that, but that's an awful lot to setup for just recording my sessions, so I thought I'd ask if there's an environment variable or something I could use instead.

Comment: `set | grep HIST`?

Comment: You can always do `history -a <FILE>` at the end of each session to save current subshell's history.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk you should make that an answer (possibly along with mentioning `HISTFILE` which Cyrus seems to be alluding to.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently answered a very similar question asked at Ask
Ubuntu:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175757/how-can-i-save-a-part-of-command-lines-into-a-new-file-using-history-command/1175763#1175763

You need to use `-a` together with a file name. As explained in `help history`:

> history: history [-c] [-d offset] [n] or history -anrw [filename] or
>   history -ps arg [arg...]
>
> (...)
>
> -a        append history lines from this session to the history file

And later on:

> If FILENAME is given, it is used as the history file.  Otherwise, if
>   $HISTFILE has a value, that is used, else ~/.bash_history.

For example, start a new session and type this (`$` is a prompt, it will most probably be different on your system):

```
$ echo a-new-session started at $(date)
$ history -a /tmp/new-history
```

In this case `/tmp/new-history` will be:

```
echo a-new-session started at $(date)
history -a /tmp/new-history
```